# Distribution Certificate is Expired

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

Today, I realized that My Distribution Certificate has expired and cannot see any certificate under distribution anymore.

Also AppStore provisioning profile is expired but still there. When I want to edit it, of course i need to create a new distribution certificate.

So the question is, will I be able to update my existing App with new certificate?

Thanks

Comment: briefly, __yes__, that is standard procedure; you need to create a new certificate and need to assign it to your distribution profile (or create a new one, whichever is easier).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when your certificates is expired making following scenario:

1.When your certificate expires, it simply disappears from the `Certificates, Identifier & Profiles` section of Member Center. There is no `Renew` button that allows you to renew your certificate.You can revoke a certificate and generate a new one before it expires. Or you can wait for it to expire and disappear, then generate a new certificate.

2.When your development or distribution certificate expires, remove it and request a new certificate in Xcode.

3.When your certificate expires or is revoked, any provisioning profile that made use of the expired/revoked certificate will be reflected as ‘Invalid’. You cannot build and sign any app using these invalid provisioning profiles. As you can imagine, I'd rather revoke and regenerate a certificate before it expires.

4.Apps that are already on the App Store continue to function fine. Again, in 
Important: Re-creating your development or distribution certificates doesn’t affect apps that you’ve submitted to the store nor does it affect your ability to update them.